# Symfony buildForm builder setName

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony project, so here's is my problem:

I have got an Entity and for that Entity I have got two forms in the same page(one for insert and the other to update the inserted).
So I made that.

**ActionMethod**

```
public function adminTareasAction(Request $request) {

    $newTareaForm = $this->createForm(TareaType::class, null, array("formType" => "newTarea"));
    $editTareasForm = $this->createForm(TareaType::class, null, array("formType" => "editTareas"));

    if($request->isMethod("POST")) {
        if(!is_null($request->request->get('newTarea'))) {
            $newTareaForm->handleRequest($request);
            if($newTareaForm->isSubmitted() && $newTareaForm->isValid()) {
                $newTarea = $newTareaForm->getData();

                $dataManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $dataManager->persist($newTarea);
                $dataManager->flush();

                return $this->redirectToRoute("admin_tareas");
            }
        }
        elseif(!is_null($request->request->get('editTareas'))) {
            $editTareasForm->handleRequest($request);
            if($editTareasForm->isSubmitted() && $editTareasForm->isValid()) {
                $newTarea = $newTareaForm->getData();

                $dataManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $dataManager->persist($newTarea);
                $dataManager->flush();

                return $this->redirectToRoute("admin_tareas");
            }
        }
    }

    $tareas = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FabricacionBundle:Tarea')->findAll();
    if(!$tareas) {
        $tareas = "No hay Tareas";
    }
    return $this->render('UsersBundle:Admin:adminTareas.html.twig', array("newTareaForm" => $newTareaForm->createView(), "editTareasForm" => $editTareasForm->createView(), "tareas" => $tareas));
}
```

**Type Class**

```
class TareaType extends AbstractType {

    private $formType;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $this->formType = $options["formType"];
        if($this->formType == "newTarea") {
            //var_dump();
            $builder
                ->add('tareaName', TextType::class)
                ->add('tareaOrden', IntegerType::class)
                ->add('submitNewTarea', SubmitType::class);
        }
        elseif($this->formType == "editTareas") {
            $builder
                ->add('newName', CollectionType::class, array("entry_type" => TextType::class, "allow_add" => true))
                ->add('newOrden', CollectionType::class, array("entry_type" => IntegerType::class, "allow_add" => true))
                ->add('deleteTarea', CollectionType::class, array("entry_type" => CheckboxType::class, "allow_add" => true))
                ->add('submitTarea', SubmitType::class);

        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'FabricacionBundle\Entity\Tarea',
            "formType" => null
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        /*if($this->formType == "newTarea") {
            return $this->formType;
        }
        elseif($this->formType == "editTareas") {
            return $this->formType;
        }*/
        return 'FabricacionBundle_tarea';
    }
}
```

The only thing I need is to change the form name and then handle them in the controller by name.

Comment: in the getBlockPrefix you can see a modification, it seems to load that function before the buildForm so the option parameter is not valid to do that

Comment: But what is the problem ?

Comment: I want to make 2 forms of the same type and change the name of the form. Or if there is another option please comment it.

Comment: I don't understand your code looks ok.You have the form type that changes when you pass the name of the form you want as option.And you have the controller action to submit the forms.What is missing/not working ?

Comment: Thats the idea, but de getBlockPrefix executes before buildForm so the name doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `getBlockPrefix()`.You are accessing you're field type by its FQCN :

```
 $newTareaForm = $this->createForm(TareaType::class, null, array("formType" => "newTarea"));
```

so you don't need to have an alias for it (wich is deprecated).

Comment: And if I want to set a name to the form?

Answer (score 0):

Well, reading the Form classes I get what I have to do.

**Just this to create the form:**

```
$newTareaForm = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder("newTarea", TareaType::class, null, array("formType" => "newTarea"))->getForm();
$editTareasForm = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder("editTareas", TareaType::class, null, array("formType" => "editTareas"))->getForm();
```

Comment: Is the same, but you can put the form name in the first parameter.